# .NET Core 1.1 in VS2017: DbContextOptionsBuilder does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer'

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

Working on a new project in VS2017, but when I enter my service for my dbContext, I get this error:

```
Error   CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 
'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first 
argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a 
using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v1.1.1 not include this function anymore or am I missing something?

**.csproj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable- 
net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
<ApplicationIcon />
<OutputTypeEx>exe</OutputTypeEx>
<StartupObject />
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" 
Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" 
/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" 
Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" 
Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" 
Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" 
Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" 
Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" 
Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" 
Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Novell.Directory.ldap.netstandard" 
Version="2.3.6" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference 
Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Doh! You're right. I guess I just got used to VS2015 giving the option to add those references when an error is thrown. Thanks Henk!

Comment: I'll make it an answer so we can close this up. Or you can delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error says,

> ... (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It's an extension method so you do need `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: How does one spot extension methods - this gets me all the time - most frustrating?

Answer (score 2):

I had to install 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' from NuGet.

In the Package Manager Console I ran: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 1.1.2`

I also had to ensure that I referenced Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore with a using statement: `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` in the Startup.cs file.